# Material-ui needs webpack compile in server side rendering, howto?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, material-ui, server-side-rendering

I'm new to react, and I'm trying to add ssr to my project. My issue is that when running the compiled code, there's an error complaining about the syntax of the Typography component:

```
D:\work\weallyServer\server\node_modules\@material-ui\core\es\Typography\Typography.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import _extends from "@babel/runtime/helpers/extends";
                                                                     ^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at new Script (vm.js:80:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:274:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:326:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:664:28)
    at Module._compile (D:\work\weallyServer\server\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:99:24)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (D:\work\weallyServer\server\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:104:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at eval (webpack:///external_%22@material-ui/core/es/Typography/Typography%22?:1:18)
    at Object.@material-ui/core/es/Typography/Typography (D:\work\weallyServer\server\build\index.bundle.js:1990:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\work\weallyServer\server\build\index.bundle.js:20:30)
    at eval (webpack:///./src/client/comp/ShopSuggestBox.js?:30:101)
```

What I find weired is that [material-ui says](https://material-ui.com/guides/minimizing-bundle-size/) in the section **ECMAScript** : 
The package published on npm is transpiled, with Babel, to take into account the [supported platforms](https://material-ui.com/getting-started/supported-platforms/). (which includes node 6.x and above)

I don't know what i did wrong (I'm using yarn, but I don't think it is different)

My project structure is all sources in src, with a client folder containing the material and react code as follows:

```
10/05/2019  12:10    <REP>          client
10/05/2019  10:43    <REP>          bridge
10/05/2019  10:43    <REP>          business
10/05/2019  10:43    <REP>          constants
10/05/2019  10:43    <REP>          dataset
10/05/2019  10:43    <REP>          db
10/05/2019  10:43    <REP>          graphql
10/05/2019  15:10    <REP>          public
10/05/2019  10:43    <REP>          routes
10/05/2019  15:25             3 649 facebook.js
18/04/2019  10:55            56 405 categories.js
18/04/2019  10:55             4 461 procedures.js
10/05/2019  17:37             8 801 server.js
18/04/2019  10:55               762 serverConfig.js
10/05/2019  15:22               234 starter.js
```

My webpack.config.js

```
import path from 'path';

import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')

console.log( "skipping ", path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules") )

module.exports = {
  entry: path.join(__dirname,'src','starter.js'),
  target: 'node',
  node: {
    // Need this when working with express, otherwise the build fails
    __dirname: false,   // if you don't put this is, __dirname
    __filename: false,  // and __filename return blank or /
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname,'build'),
    filename: 'index.bundle.js'
  },
  mode: process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development',
  resolve: {
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), path.resolve(__dirname, '..','src'), 'node_modules']
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname,'..','src')
  },
  externals: [nodeExternals()], 
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        // this is so that we can compile any React,
        // ES6 and above into normal ES5 syntax
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        // we do not want anything from node_modules to be compiled
        exclude: [path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules")],
//        include: [path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules", "@material-ui")],
        use: ['babel-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|mp3|svg|css)$/,
        loaders: ['file-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'public','index.html')
    })
  ]
};
```

and finally my .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/env",
    "@babel/react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
  ]
}
```

Searching the web [it confirmed](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/362) that the material-ui components have to be compiled 
What is weired is that in the [material-ui docs, they say all components work in ssr](https://material-ui.com/guides/server-rendering/)

Please be assured it took me a day to arrive to this result, and I'm still stuck, any hepl is really welcome

Here's the package.json content

```
{
  "name": "weally",
  "version": "1.0.0-beta",
  "description": "weally server",
  "main": "server.js",
  "author": "Zied Hamdi",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN LICENSE",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "webpack": "babel-node ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack",
    "start": "babel-node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server --open",
    "startProd": "node ./build/index.bundle.js"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "react",
    "webpack",
    "babel",
    "material-design"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/node": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "file-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "webpack": "^4.31.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.3.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@google/maps": "^0.5.5",
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.8.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.2",
    "apollo-boost": "^0.1.10",
    "apollo-link-context": "^1.0.9",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "csv-parse": "^4.3.1",
    "dotenv": "^6.0.0",
    "ejs": "^2.6.1",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "express-fileupload": "^1.0.0",
    "express-graphql": "^0.6.12",
    "express-jwt": "^5.3.1",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "fb": "^2.0.0",
    "graphql": "^14.0.2",
    "graphql-compose": "^6.3.1",
    "graphql-compose-connection": "^5.0.0",
    "graphql-compose-mongoose": "^6.1.0",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.9.2",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^0.19.0",
    "i18next": "^11.3.6",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.0",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "mongoose": "^5.5.2",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-facebook": "^2.1.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "paypal-checkout": "^4.0.257",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "q": "^1.5.1",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-apollo": "^2.1.7",
    "react-autosuggest": "^9.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-i18next": "^7.8.1",
    "react-image-gallery": "^0.8.12",
    "react-moment": "^0.7.9",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.3",
    "react-stripe-checkout": "^2.6.3",
    "sharp": "^0.21.0",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.10",
    "stripe": "^6.28.0",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, mia culpa:

I finally found the error was that I was importing a bad version of Typography : from **core\es** instead of from **core**

The autocomplete in my IDE took his gained time back :)